# AWS server became slow after traffic increase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, api, amazon-web-services

I have a single page Angular app that makes request to a Rails API service. Both are running on a t2xlarge Ubuntu instance. I am using a Postgres database.

We had increase in traffic, and my Rails API became slow. Sometimes, I get an error saying Passenger queue full for rails application.

Auto scaling on the server is working; three more instances are created. But I cannot trace this issue. I need root access to upgrade, which I do not have. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that you are using T2.2xlarge instance type. Firstly I want to tell you should not use T2 instance type for production environment. Cause of T2 instance uses `CPU Credit`. Lets take a look on [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html)

> **What happens if I use all of my credits?**
>
> If your instance uses all of its CPU credit balance, performance
>   remains at the baseline performance level. If your instance is running
>   low on credits, your instance’s CPU credit consumption (and therefore
>   CPU performance) is gradually lowered to the base performance level
>   over a 15-minute interval, so you will not experience a sharp
>   performance drop-off when your CPU credits are depleted. If your
>   instance consistently uses all of its CPU credit balance, **we recommend
>   a larger T2 size or a fixed performance instance type such as M3 or
>   C3**.

Im not sure you won't face to the `out of CPU Credit problem` because you are using Xlarge type but I think you should use other `fixed performance instance types`. So instance's performace maybe one part of your problem. You should use cloudwatch to monitor on 2 metrics: `CPUCreditUsage and CPUCreditBalance` to make sure the problem.

Secondly, how about your `ASG`? After scale-out, did your service become stable? If so, I think you do not care about this problem any more because ASG did what it's reponsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following

- If you are opening a connection to Database, make sure you close it.

  - If you are using jquery, bootstrap, datatables, or other css libraries, use the CDN links like

  `<link rel="stylesheet" ref="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">`

  - it will reduce a great amount of load on your server. do not copy the jquery or other external libraries on your own server when you can directly fetch it from other servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors that can cause an EC2 instance (or any system) to appear to run slowly.

1. CPU Usage. The higher the CPU usage the longer to process new threads and processes.
2. Free Memory. Your system needs free memory to process threads, create new processes, etc. How much free memory do you have?
3. Free Disk Space. Operating systems tend to thrash when the file systems on system drives run low on free disk space. How much free disk space do you have?
4. Network Bandwidth. What is the average bytes in / out for your
   instance?
5. Database. Monitor connections, free memory, disk bandwidth, etc.

Amazon has CloudWatch which can provide you with monitoring for everything except for free disk space (you can add an agent to your instance for this metric). This will also help you quickly see what is happening with your instances.

Monitor your EC2 instances and your database.

You mention T2 instances. These are burstable CPUs which means that if you have consistenly higher CPU usage, then you will want to switch to fixed performance EC2 instances. CloudWatch should help you figure out what you need (CPU or Memory or Disk or Network performance).

Answer (score 0):

This is totally independent of AWS Server. Looks like your software needs more juice (RAM, StorageIO, Network) and it is not sufficient with one machine. You need to evaluate the metric using cloudwatch and adjust software needs based on what is required for the software.

It could be memory leaks or processing leaks that may lead to this as well. You need to create clusters or server farm to handle the load.

Hope it helps.